# Directory change error with mingw32-make

Tags: makefile, mingw, mingw32, poco-libraries

I'm building POCO library 1.6.0 under MinGW32, environment: Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit, shell: MSYS. Successfully executed *./configure*.

```
$ ./configure
Configured for MinGW
```

Contents of config.make:

```
POCO_CONFIG = MinGW
POCO_BASE = /c/dev/poco
POCO_BUILD = /c/dev/poco
POCO_PREFIX = /usr/local
POCO_FLAGS = 
OMIT = 
export POCO_CONFIG
export POCO_BASE
export POCO_BUILD
export POCO_PREFIX
export POCO_FLAGS
```

After launching mingw32-make I'm getting:

```
$ mingw32-make --debug -w
GNU Make 3.82
Built for i386-pc-mingw32
Copyright (C) 2010  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Reading makefiles...
Updating goal targets....
 File `poco' does not exist.
   File `libexecs' does not exist.
     File `Foundation-libexec' does not exist.
    Must remake target `Foundation-libexec'.
Invoking recipe from Makefile:69 to update target `Foundation-libexec'.
mingw32-make: Entering directory `c:/dev/poco'
C:/app/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make -d -C /c/dev/poco/Foundation
GNU Make 3.82
Built for i386-pc-mingw32
Copyright (C) 2010  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
mingw32-make: Entering an unknown directory
mingw32-make: *** /c/dev/poco/Foundation: No such file or directory.  Stop.
mingw32-make: Leaving an unknown directory
mingw32-make: *** [Foundation-libexec] Error 2
mingw32-make: Leaving directory `c:/dev/poco'
```

The problem is in

```
mingw32-make: Entering an unknown directory
mingw32-make: *** /c/dev/poco/Foundation: No such file or directory.  Stop.
```

because */c/dev/poco/Foundation* does exist:

```
$ ls
CHANGELOG       LICENSE   VERSION                  build_vs110.cmd  config.make
CMakeLists.txt  MANIFEST  XML                      build_vs120.cmd  configure
CONTRIBUTORS    Makefile  build                    build_vs90.cmd   contrib
CppUnit         NEWS      build_CE_vs90.cmd        buildwin.cmd     doc
DLLVersion.rc   Net       build_vcexpress2008.cmd  cmake            libversion
Foundation      README    build_vcexpress2010.cmd  components       patches
JSON            Util      build_vs100.cmd          config.build
```

I was modifying *makefile* to change directory to other sub-folders, no joy. It seems like something prevents *mingw32-make* from changing directory. Also can confirm that

```
cd /c/dev/poco/Foundation
```

works fine.

Tried with *make*, result is the same:

```
$ make --debug -w
GNU Make 3.82
Built for i386-pc-mingw32
Copyright (C) 2010  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Reading makefiles...
Updating goal targets....
 File `poco' does not exist.
   File `libexecs' does not exist.
     File `Foundation-libexec' does not exist.
    Must remake target `Foundation-libexec'.
Invoking recipe from Makefile:69 to update target `Foundation-libexec'.
make: Entering directory `c:/dev/poco'
C:/app/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make -d -C /c/dev/poco/Foundation
GNU Make 3.82
Built for i386-pc-mingw32
Copyright (C) 2010  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
make: Entering an unknown directory
make: *** /c/dev/poco/Foundation: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: Leaving an unknown directory
make: *** [Foundation-libexec] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `c:/dev/poco'
```

There are no obvious reasons for *mingw32-make* to fail as path does not have spaces.

What I have missed? Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: which [build configuration](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/tree/develop/build/config) are you using? did you run [configure](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/configure)? what is the value of $POCO_BASE?

Comment: I did, extended the original post to answer your questions

Comment: I've installed fresh recent MinGW environment and build works fine; with MinGW-specific modifications of course, but this is a different story.

So the problem was at least with make.exe, maybe also with something else as environment was quite old.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The path `/c/dev/poco/Foundation` does not mean what you seem to think, in the context of `mingw32-make.exe`. See, `mingw32-make.exe` is a *native* Windows application, so it *definitely* will *not* understand an `MSYS` specific path such as `/c/dev/poco/Foundation`; rather, it will interpret it "as is", as `c:/c/dev/poco/Foundation`, (assuming your current working drive is `c:`), which I'm sure is not what you intended.

You do seem to be using `MSYS` as your shell, so why are you using `mingw32-make.exe` anyway? Use the `make.exe` that `MSYS` itself provides; it does understand `MSYS` paths.

Do note that, if you run `make --version` from the MSYS shell, you *should* see, (at this time of writing):

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i686-pc-msys
```

In your updated question, you show an example of running `make.exe`, which clearly is *not* this MSYS version; it appears that *you* have placed an alternative version of `make.exe` -- perhaps even a copy of `mingw32-make.exe` itself, for the output is identical -- in some directory which precedes the MSYS version in your `$PATH`. You should delete this non-MSYS version of `make.exe`; the entire purpose in calling the MinGW version `mingw32-make.exe` is to avoid this very conflict. When you run `make` from the MSYS shell, you want the MSYS version, and *not* some `mingw32-make.exe` clone.

Comment: Thank you Keith, done the tests you suggested and extended the description - after using make.exe build still fails

Comment: @Andriy, then you'll need to include a _minimal_ self-contained sample makefile, which demonstrates the problem. Are you _sure_ that your `make.exe` is from `MSYS`? The current _official_ version from MinGW.org is GNU-Make-3.81-3, yet your output shows 3.82.

Comment: @Andriy, your MSYS `make.exe` _should_ proclaim itself as `GNU Make 3.81`, with footnote: `This program built for i686-pc-msys`.  The version you've shown, in your follow-up test, looks more like a copy of `mingw32-make.exe`; you need to get rid of that.

Comment: Your observation is correct, I've posted the answer